# Can't get nested comments to work with ancestry gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to implement replies for my comments in rails. I was watching this video as a guideline http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry
All the comments I create just becomes the root node, everytime I try replying to a comment it seems like it just doesn't register as the children node.
(I've checked with rails console and the column 'ancestry' for the replying comment is always nil)

My comment is a nested resources under the Post Model. I suspect the problem is with the create function in the comments controller?

using rails '4.2.4'

Comments controller:

```
def new
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]) 
    @comment = @post.comments.build
    @comment.parent_id = params[:parent_id]

end

def create

    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user

    if @comment.save
        redirect_to build_post_path(@post)
    else
        redirect_to build_post_path(@post)
    end
end
```

comments/new.html.erb

```
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 ">
            <h3>Reply</h3>
            <ol class ="comments">
                <%= render @comment.parent if @comment.parent %>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>


    <%= render 'form' %>
```

comments/_form.html.erb

```
<div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
            <%= form_for([@post, Comment.new]) do |f| %>

                  <%= render 'shared/error_messages',object: f.object %>

                  <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>

                  <%= f.label :comment %>
                  <%= f.text_area :comment , class: 'form-control', rows: "4"  %>

                  <div class = "row">
                        <div class = "col-md-3">
                              <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                        </div>
                  </div>
            <% end %>
      </div>
</div>
```

comments/_comments.html.erb

```
<li id="comment-<%= comment.id %>">

  <span class="avatar"><%= image_tag(comment.user.avatar.url(:thumb)) %></span>
  <span class="user"><%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %> <span class = "timestamp"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago.</span></span>
  <span class="content"><%= comment.comment %></span>
  <span class="options">

    <%= link_to "Index", post_comments_path %> | 

    <%= link_to "Reply", new_post_comment_path(:parent_id => comment) %> |

    <% if current_user?(comment.user) %>
      <%= link_to "Delete", [comment.post, comment], method: :delete,
                                       data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_comment_path(comment.post, comment) %>
    <% end %>
  </span>

</li>
```

post/show.html.erb

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 ">
        <h3>Comments (<%= @post.comments.count %>)</h3>
        <ol class ="comments">
            <%= nested_messages @post.comments.arrange(:order => :created_at) %>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

helper method

```
def nested_messages(messages)
    messages.map do |message, sub_messages|
      render(message) + content_tag(:div, nested_messages(sub_messages), :class => "nested_messages")
    end.join.html_safe
  end
```

Comment: Common pitfall... did you include the parameter in the comment_params?

Comment: And also check if the hidden parent_id form has the value of the parent comment when you click on reply!

Comment: Thanks for the first advice, i didn't add the parent_id to the comment params! However, the hidden parent_id value isn't being passed to the create function. I know this because i entered it manually, and the nested comment worked! I don't know why it isn't being passed though...

Comment: I fixed it! I did 
<%= f.hidden_field :parent_id , :value => @comment.parent_id %>
Thanks so much you don't know how long I've been banging my head on this, still very new to rails

Comment: See my code sample as answer, I think you can achieve this without this addition!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling Comment.new in the form declaration although you have already initiated a new comment in the new method, change your form call to this:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

I think by making that addition, you do not have to manually set the value of the parent_comment.

Comment: I tried that before, but it wasn't working because I didn't include the parent_id in the params, but now that I have, I can use it again! Thanks!